# Advantage of using Immutablemap guava

Tags: guava

I had a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) but still not sure why or when should I use a Guava Immutablemap when I can have a java.util.Map and make it final.

Please can someone explain the advantages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *final* map just means that the reference (pointer) cannot change. You can still mutate the contents of the map (e.g., map.put(k, v), map.remove(k), etc.).

An *immutable* map is one that you cannot mutate the contents. You cannot add, remove, or clear the map.

For the many advantages of immutable collections, please see [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).